# Compare and Replace inline using Awk/Sed command

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file (fixed length) in which searching for consecutive 2 lines starting with number 30 and then comparing value in position 183-187 and if both matching printing the line number. I am able to achieve the desired results up to this stage. But I would like to replace the value present in the line number with empty spaces without tampering the fixed length.

`awk '/^30*/a=substr($0,183,187);getline;b=substr($0,183,187); if(a==b) print NR}' file`

Explanation of the command above:
line number start with 30*
assign value to a from position between 183 to 187
get next line
assign value to b from position between 183 to 187
compare a & b - if matches it proves the value between 183 to 187 in 2 consecutive lines which starts with 30.
print line number (this is the 2nd match line number)

Above command is working as expected and printing the line number.

Example Record (just for explanation purpose hence not used fixed length)

```
10        ABC
20        XXX
30        XYZ
30        XYZ
30        XYZ
30        XYZ
40        YYY
10        ABC
20        XXX
30        XYZ
30        XYZ
40        YYY
```

With above command I could able to get line number 3 and 4 but unable to replace the 4th line output with empty spaces (inline replace) so that fixed width will not get compromised

Expected Output

```
10        ABC
20        XXX
30        XYZ
30       
30       
30       
40        YYY
10        ABC
20        XXX
30        XYZ
30       
40        YYY
```

Length of all the above lines should be 255 chars - when replace happens it has to be inline without adding it as new spaces.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^30/{N;s/^(.{182}(.{5}).*\n.{182})\2/\1     /}' file
```

Match on a line beginning `30` and append the following line.

Using pattern matching, if the 5 characters from 183-187 for both lines are the same, replace the second group of 5 characters with 5 spaces.

---

For multiple adjacent lines use:

```
sed -E '/^30/{:a;N;s/^(.{182}(.{5}).*\n.{182})\2/\1     /;ta}' file
```

Or alternative:

```
sed -E ':a;$!N;s/^(30.{180}(\S{5}).*\n.{182})\2/\1     /;ta;P;D' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the above command. I used -i option to make it inplace replace. Could you please help to explain above command how it picks up next line. I am new to sed, it will help for my learning. Thanks again.

Comment: @Keyan the `N` command appends the next line to pattern space ( the buffer holding the current line).

Comment: Thanks. If I have to check and replace not only next line and also next to next line then is there an option available for that one as well? - Updated orginal question with an example dataset

Comment: @Keyan see edit for multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` and treat every character as field, consider following example, let `file.txt` content be

```
10 ABC
20 XXX
30 XYZ
30 XYZ
40 YYY
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=".";OFS=""}prev~/^30*/{a=substr(prev,4,3);b=substr($0,4,3);if(a==b){$4=$5=$6=" "}}{print}{prev=$0}' file.txt
```

output

```
10 ABC
20 XXX
30 XYZ
30    
40 YYY
```

Explanation: I elected to use storing whole line in variable called `prev` rather than using `getline`, thus I do `{prev=$0}` as last action. I set `FPAT` to `.` indicating that any single character should be treated as field and `OFS` (output field separator) to empty string so no unwanted character will be added during line preparing. If `prev` (previous line or empty string for first line) starts with `3` I get substring with characters 4,5,6 from previous line (`prev`) and store it in variable `a` and get substring with characters 4,5,6 from current line (`$0`) and store it in variable `b`, if `a` and `b` are equal I change 4th, 5th and 6th character to space each. No matter it was changed or not I `print` line. Disclaimer: this assume that you want to deal with at most 2 subsequent lines having equal substring. Note `/^30*/` does not check if string starts with `30` but rather if it does start with `3` e.g. it will match `312`, you should probably use `/^30/` instead, I elected to use your pattern unchanged as you imply it does work as intended for your data.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to test this one as well to see if it helps in my case. Thanks for the detailed explanation. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you want, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v tgt=30 -v beg=11 -v end=13 '
    ($1==tgt) && seen[$1]++ { $0=substr($0,1,beg-1) sprintf("%*s",end-beg,"") substr($0,end+1) }
1' file
10        ABC
20        XXX
30        XYZ
30
40        YYY
```

Just change `-v beg=11 -v end=13` to `beg=183 -v end=187` for your real data.

If you're ever again tempted to use `getline` make sure to read awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first as it's usually the wrong approach.